# bitcoin setup using nodejs

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development, node.js

I have to to use bitcoin api using nodejs. but I cannot understand from where I have to start.Search some node module like bitcoin-core and bitcoin.

Can anyone describe the step how can I set up bitcoin in our system and use using nodejs.
Also refer some link where use of bitcoin api request and response parameter are describe in nodejs.

I have to use bitcoin json-rpc api's with node.js but dont know from where i can start?

Comment: As it is written, this question doesn't make a lot of sense.  You seem to need to do something with Bitcion, but haven't specified what that is.  Without that information, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I m using bitcore for stand alone rpc because it has many new indexes and new methods.

See this link https://bitcore.io/guides/bitcoin

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, install bitcoin-core. I recommend compiling it yourself but there are binaries available for download. You'll want to perform all the steps in this tutorial - follow all steps for the *daemon*. Do not do the *graphical user interface* steps. https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1610

Run the daemon and use bitcoin-cli to familiarize yourself with the Bitcoin RPC API. https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#other-linux-distributions

Start the daemon, such that it creates the right folders.
`bitcoind -daemon`
Stop it after a few seconds.
`bitcoin-cli stop`

You should see a new folder `.bitcoind` in your HOME directory. (Or AppData if you're on Windows). You'll need to add this file into it as 'bitcoin.conf':

> rpcuser=YOURUSERNAME
>
> rpcpassword=YOURPASSWORD

Replace YOURUSERNAME with a username of your choice, same for the password. Remember these as you'll need it for configuring your NodeJS app.

`bitcoind -daemon`

Get the balance:
`bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=YOURUSERNAME -rpcpassword=YOURPASSWORD getbalance`

Pick a nice Bitcoin Core JSON-RPC Node module, like this one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bitcoin-rpc
^Also has the get balance example.

They use the same commands that you enter in the bitcoin-cli.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to proceed is to make your own client.

Here is mine on PHP. Even if you do not know PHP, you can see how easy is to create one from scratch:

JSONRPC:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/BlockchainWalker/blob/master/jsonrpc.php

Selected Bitcoind commands I need:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/BlockchainWalker/blob/master/bitcoindrpc.php

### update:

In case you do own client, make sure you handle first transaction

"**4a5e1e4baab89f3a32518a88c31bc87f618f76673e2cc77ab2127b7afdeda33b**"

in special code, because bitcoind can not handle it.